# How to generate an invoice from a custom module in Odoo13?

Tags: odoo, invoice, odoo-13

I am developing a custom module.

I tried to add it through an object button with the following code but doesn't seem to work

```py
    def create_invoice(self):
        rslt = self.env['account.invoice'].create({
                    'partner_id': self.instructor.id,
                    'name': 'customer invoice',
                    'type': 'out_invoice',
                    'date_invoice': 'create_date'
                })
        return rslt
```

How can I add a button that generates an invoice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

desu

From `Odoo13` there is a change in invoice object, It is now `account.move` instead of `account.invoice`.You can take this reference **demo** example.

```
invoice = self.env['account.move'].create({
    'type': 'out_invoice', 
    'journal_id': journal.id,
    'partner_id': product_id.id,
    'invoice_date': date_invoice,
    'date': date_invoice,
    'invoice_line_ids': [(0, 0, {
        'product_id': product_id.id,
        'quantity': 40.0,
        'name': 'product test 1',
        'discount': 10.00,
        'price_unit': 2.27,
    })]
})
```

Comment: What about the tax id? I know that you can add multiple tax id's, but how do you do it via the code?

Comment: tax_id is the many2many then you can add data like this, [(6, 0, IDS] @MihaiPop